# Intermittent fault in ASP.NET MVC web app: ManagedPipelineHandler taking 30s to set Cache-Control header then sets HTTP status 500

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

We have a .NET Framework 4.6.1 ASP.NET MVC web app that throws a 500 internal server error several times a day.  I noticed in the IIS logs whenever this happens the request time-taken is almost exactly 30 seconds (varies between 30000 ms and about 30020 ms) whereas the successful requests are much more random, taking between 16 seconds and about 90 seconds (the web app generates and downloads a large PDF report, hence why it takes so long).

The app has no internal logging.  I enabled failed request logging for the 500 error.  I've looked at 3 failed request traces and they all show the same pattern: The ManagedPipelineHandler taking around 30 seconds to set the Cache-Control response header to "private" before setting the HTTP Status to 500.  Here is a sample failed request trace:

[image: Failed request trace showing ManagedPipelineHandler setting Cache-Control response header and HTTP Status]

Is there something special about the Cache-Control header that would cause the pipeline to hang while setting its value?  Or does this trace just indicate that the pipeline is running the application code between setting the X-AspNetMvc-Version header and the Cache-Control header?

I've tried to find information about how the pipeline works and particularly about when it sets the response headers versus when it runs the application code but I haven't found a useful overview.

Comment: In short that FRT log indicates your controller took that long to generate an HTTP response with 500.0 and that's the thing (timeout? unhandled exception?) you must analyze further.

Comment: Thanks Lex.  I suspected it would be the application, not the pipeline setting the Cache-Control header, that was taking the time but I couldn't be sure as I couldn't find any info confirming that.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description. When the server hangs, crashes or performance is low, 
it is usually necessary to grab the server's thread stack (Thread Dump) for subsequent analysis. 
So I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com, 
there will be professional technicians to assist you in grabbing the dump file and analyzing it.